# Handling time-out in C client-server program

Tags: c, sockets, timeout

I have a small client-server program, and I want to close the connection to the client after 10 sec of max time-out. I have an alarm and the function that closes the connection and the alarm handler look like this:

```
void closeClient() {
    int nr = close(conn);
    if (nr == 0)
       printf("Client connection closed.\n");
    else {
      printf("Error while closing client connection. Error code: %d\n",errno);
      exit(1);
    }
    exit(0); // Process ends after serving the client
}

void time_out(int signal) {  
    printf("Time out.\n");

    char* msg = "Time out.Connection to server is closed\n\0";
    send(conn, msg, strlen(msg),0);
    closeClient(conn);  
    exit(1);
}
```

The problem is that the client prints the message("Time-out.Connection to the server closed") only if it tries to send something to the server (after the connection is already closed). I can't figure out why. Some suggestions?

Comment: you never show code where time_out function is called.

Comment: It's something like this: `code` signal(SIGALRM, time_out);
  alarm(10);
            
    cod = recv(conn, &buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    boolean isNumber = validateNumber(buf);
    printf("String received:%s\n", buf);
    alarm(0); // stop the timer   
    if(!isNumber) {   //The server didn't receive a valid integer
        errorMsg = "Please enter a valid integer!\n\0";
        printf("Sending error message..\n");
        send(conn, errorMsg, strlen(errorMsg)+1, 0);
    }
    else.. `code`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [select()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) and give it a timeout value in the last argument?

Something along:

```
fd_set readset;
struct timeval timeout = {10, 0}; // 10 sec. timeout
FD_ZERO( &readset)
FD_SET( conn, &readset);
int status = select( conn+1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
if(status == 0) // timeout reached
{
   // close conn
}
else if(status == -1)
{
   // handle error
}
else
{
   // data ready to be received
   status = read(conn, ....);
}
```

Be sure to check your return values each time.

Comment: I'm ok with the way I'm handling time_out and it works fine, or to me it seems so. Meaning that the server waits for 10 seconds to receive a string; if it receives the string, it resets the alarm. The problem is with the signal handler (time_out() function) at the point where I send the message to the client. This message doesn't appear when it should, only after the client tries to send smth to the server, the connection being already closed. I didn't work for a long long time in C, so sorry if I'm not explaining myself very clear.

Comment: My bad, I didn't answer the core of the question. For this though, I (we?) might need to see the code on your client side. Maybe you don't flush the print buffer? Try adding `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` in the init of your client?

Comment: This kinda sum's it up: `code` printf("Type the number you want:\n");
  fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
  
  if (input[strlen(input)-1] == '\n') {
     input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0'; //for full line read
     cod = send(conn, input, strlen(input), 0);

    if (cod != strlen(input)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error at sending data to the server..\n");
        return 1;
    }   
    //Server's response:
    cod = recv(conn, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    printf("Server's response is:\n\t %s \n", buf);
`code`  I've tried setbuf(stdout, NULL), just before recv, but still no result.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it waits indefinitely for input because of fgets(), but I don't know how to treat this special case. I would like ideas of  some mechanism to force output on the client.

Comment: @joanna It's almost impossible to read code posted in comments, instead, edit your question and post/format the code theere.